# Way to programmatically exclude/include certain js files/directories in Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I've tried a number of ways to programmatically, via .erb extensions, include/exclude files using //= require xyz in the application.js file. However it doesn't work, it just has the requires as comments. Basically I want to include a js directory when the Rails.env.test? is true otherwise I don't want to include it. Is there a way to do that?

```
    <% if Rails.env.test? %>
    //= require mapper.base
    //= require mapper.google
    <% end %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore certain files in the asset pipeline when performing assets:precompile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116671/ignore-certain-files-in-the-asset-pipeline-when-performing-assetsprecompile)